# Encrypting MSMQ

Tags: firewall, encryption, msmq, activemq, wcf

So I want to do asynchronous, disconnected, across-the-Internet messaging with WCF. Probably due to my background in Apache ActiveMQ, I'm looking at MSMQ for this.

In ActiveMQ, it was a simple thing to encrypt a queue connection; you simply chose an SSL based connection to the broker, and you had a basic SSL layer to protect your communication between the broker and the clients.  (Should I consider using WCF clients with an ActiveMQ broker?)

When I hit Google for MSMQ encryption and MSMQ SSL I'm not finding anything similar. Here's hoping I'm just missing something?

I have found some semi-convoluted looking stuff about encrypting messages, things that seem off the mark about using HTTPS, and things that require an Active Directory - but I'm looking to protect all of the communication, not just the messages, and we prefer not to use HTTPS as a binding as we require disconnected operation, and we will have no Active Directory to work with.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally found a reference to doing non-Active Directory MSMQ encryption. Here's the link.  It's not hard once you find the documentation!

This is how you use message encryption with MSMQ but not use Active Directory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395200.aspx

From TFA:

> Demonstrates
>
> The client encrypts the message using
>   the public key of the service and
>   signs the message using its own
>   certificate. The service reading the
>   message from the queue authenticates
>   the client certificate with the
>   certificate in its trusted people
>   store. It then decrypts the message
>   and dispatches the message to the
>   service operation.
>
> Because the Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) message is carried as
>   a payload in the body of the MSMQ
>   message, the body remains encrypted in
>   the MSMQ store. This secures the
>   message from unwanted disclosure of
>   the message. Note that MSMQ itself is
>   not aware whether the message it is
>   carrying is encrypted.
>
> The sample demonstrates how mutual
>   authentication at the message level
>   can be used with MSMQ. The
>   certificates are exchanged
>   out-of-band. This is always the case
>   with queued application because the
>   service and the client do not have to
>   be up and running at the same time.
>
> Description The sample client and
>   service code are the same as the
>   Transacted MSMQ Binding sample with
>   one difference. The operation contract
>   is annotated with protection level,
>   which suggests that the message must
>   be signed and encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Does http://blogs.msdn.com/motleyqueue/archive/2007/10/06/complementing-msmq-security-with-wcf.aspx have any relevance?  It seems to hint at a setting which appears to be transport level, and suggests message encryption as well.

Comment: This looks good so far. Upvoting you for now, will try it later.